# adding readability view to iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, readability

How can I have a readability view for a particular URL, just like what tweetbot has in their new update? I tried looking at their website and API and it seems that this is not an API feature. So what is this then?

Comment: Check out my answeer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961509/readability-in-my-application/14290141